# How to create relations in database Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, model, entity-relationship, laravel-5

I have two table: users and projects. In projects admin can add projects like:
web design, SEO , etc.... I need to add abilty to admin can add some users to certain project...

For example I need users with id 2,3 to be for web design project and users 4,5,6 to be in SEO poroject.

Any idea or example?

Comment: Try to add a many to many relation on user<->projects.

Comment: Any example how can do that with Laravel 5?

Comment: Im not familiar with laravel-5 but: thats the first result if u search for **laravel-5 many to many relation**: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/21

Comment: start by sharing your code example here for users and projects tables